# PropertyChanged event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, inotifypropertychanged

I have a question about the `PropertyChanged` event firing from a base class.  So I have a base class, called `MainWindowBase` with a property called SelectedItem and a collection called Items, actually derived in a lower base class.  I populate Items, then set SelectedItem from the derived class, which calls the base class setter on SelectedItem.  The `SelectedItem.PropertyChanged` handler is never called in the derived class.  Why?

class `MainWindowViewModel`:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : MainWindowBase<DocumentBase>
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Items.AddRange(new ObservableCollection<PositionViewModel>()
        {
          new PositionViewModel { Name = "Test Case 1" },
          new PositionViewModel { Name = "Test Case 2" },
          new PositionViewModel { Name = "Test Case 3" }
        });

        SelectedItem = Items.FirstOrDefault();

        SelectedItem.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SelectedItem changed!");
        };


        PropertyChanged += MainWindowViewModelPropertyChanged;

        SelectedItem = Items[1];
    }

    public void MainWindowViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

class `MainWindowBase`:

```
public class MainWindowBase<TDocument> : Conductor<TDocument>.Collection.OneActive
    where TDocument : DocumentBase, new()
{

    private TDocument selectedItem;

    public TDocument SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            selectedItem = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

`PositionViewModel` class:

```
public class PositionViewModel : DocumentBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`DocumentBase` is simply derived from `Screen`.

Thanks for looking at this, and let me know in the comments if you need any more information.  Basically `Debug.WriteLine()` is never called, but `MainWindowViewModelPropertyChanged()` is.  I would like to just handle a property change for a specific property (`SelectedItem`) in this case.

Comment: Not sure if I totally understand your code, but a sanity check: do any of the classes in your hierarchy actually declare that they implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes, both Conductor (or rather one of its base classes) and Screen implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Note that `Items.AddRange(new ObservableCollection<PositionViewModel>()` doesn't make sense. I suppose `Items` is a `List`. `AddRange` just adds items into list, it doesn't matter what `IEnumerable<T>` you will pass as an argument. So you can use just `new[] { ... }`. It is shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The `PropertyChanged` event is fired after a property of a class was changed**. Or in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) words:

> Notifies clients that a property value has changed. [...] For example, consider a Person object with a property called FirstName.

The `SelectedItem` property is defined in `MainWindowBase` and inherited to `MainWindowViewModel`. This means if the `SelectedItem` was changed the event fires inside the class the property contains (`MainWindowViewModel` in your case).

The `PositionViewModel` is not recognizing if it is selected or not. The `PropertyChanged` event of it is only called if a property inside itself was changed. Since you are not calling `NotifyOfPropertyChange` inside the class this is never possible (except `DocumentBase` is firing the event).

If you need to do specific actions at selection or deselection you can use the setter to call a method. Here is a basic example:

```
private TDocument selectedItem;
public TDocument SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedItem?.YouAreNotSelected();
        value?.YouAreSelected();
        selectedItem = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps.  What I want to do in the PropertyChanged event handler or in MainWindowViewModelPropertyChanged is assign the SelectedItem (according to its derived type) to a PositionViewModel type property in another viewmodel.

Comment: You could handle that inside the setter by checking the type of `value`.

Comment: I don't generally like to put that much logic in property setters. Thanks for the explanation though, it makes perfect sense.